# Examples of two-dimensional Riemannian manifolds that can't be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Can anyone give some examples of two-dimensional Riemannian manifolds $(M,g)$ that can't be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^4$? (Further more Globally)

What if it is smooth?

Comment: Poznyak proved that every two-dimensional Riemannian manifold locally isometrically embeds into $\mathbb{R}^4$. Globally, you need $\mathbb{R}^{10}$.

Comment: Lots of obvious examples: all surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and all products of plane curves, so lots of flat tori.

Comment: Can you list some counterexamples that can't embedd into R^4 globally thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I found the following in the notes to chapter 2 of the book of Han and Hong: "Isometric embedding of Riemannian manifolds in Euclidean spaces" which is a great source for questions about isometric immersions and embeddings.

The real projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$ (with the standard (constant Gauss curvature 1) metric from $S^2$) has no $C^2$ isometric embedding in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (in particular this rules out smooth embeddings as in your question).  Han and Hong cite [the 1970 survey "Embeddings and immersions in Riemannian geometry"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1070/RM1970v025n05ABEH003801) by Gromov and Rokhlin, in particular see Appendix 4.

This result deserves a little more comment.  Note that there do exist embeddings of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^4$, see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane#Embedding_into_4-dimensional_space).  What Gromov and Rokhlin prove is that there are none with strictly positive curvature.

Gromov and Rokhlin state that it is open whether isometric embeddings for $\mathbb{RP}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ exist for $C^r$ with $1<r<2$ (recall that for $r\leq1$, Nash-Kuiper applies).

Answer (score 8):

This is more of a remark than an answer and addresses the *weaker* condition of asking for an *immersion* rather than an embedding.

I assume that you want the immersion to be smooth (or at least $C^2$) since, otherwise, by Nash-Kuiper, there is no obstruction.

On the other hand, according to Gromov's *Partial Differential Relations* (published in 1986, so it may be out of date on this), "There is no single known obstruction for isometric $C^\infty$-immersions of surfaces into Riemannian $4$-manifolds". (See 3.2.4, pp. 289-294.)

More specifically, the last time I checked, it was unknown whether $\mathbb{RP}^2$ endowed with any metric of positive curvature could be isometrically immersed into $\mathbb{R}^4$ and it was still unknown whether the hyperbolic plane (with Gauss curvature $-1$) could be isometrically immersed in $\mathbb{R^4}$.  The latter can be isometrically embedded in $\mathbb{R}^5$, as can $\mathbb{RP}^2$ with a metric of constant positive Gauss curvature.  See Gromov's PDR for details.