# Intuition for no isometric embedding of round projective plane into $\mathbb{R}^4 $

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

This has been on MSE for over a month with four upvotes but no answers or even comments so I'm cross-posting:

According to [Examples of two-dimensional Riemannian manifolds that can't be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^4$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231495/examples-of-two-dimensional-riemannian-manifolds-that-cant-be-isometrically-emb) there is no smooth isometric embedding of the round (=constant positive curvature) projective plane into $ \mathbb{R}^4 $.

**Is there some intuition for why there is a smooth isometric embedding into $ \mathbb{R}^5 $ and even into round $ S^4 $ but not into $ \mathbb{R}^4 $?**

Some things I already know:

- There is an isometric embedding of round $ \mathbb{R}P^n $ into $ \mathbb{R}^{N} $ where $ N=\frac{n(n+3)}{2} $
- This embedding is equivariant with respect to the isometry group $ O_{n+1} $ at least for $ n=1,2 $. In fact the image of the embedding arises as the orbit of a vector with respect to an $ N $ real dimensional irreducible orthogonal representation of $ O_{n+1} $.
- It is an open question if there exists a $ C^r $ embedding of $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $ into $ \mathbb{R}^4 $ for $ 1 < r <2 $

Comment: How do you resolve any of these problems?  For example, the simpler issue of obstructing equivariant embeddings of surfaces in $S^3$ boils down to using equivariant embeddings to construct embeddings of surface bundles over $S^1$ into $S^4$, and using obstructions to $3$-manifolds embedding in $S^4$.  At least, that is one approach.  In your case you have a larger symmetry group, so you would be constructing a bigger bundle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure what you would accept as 'intuition' for this result.  It's actually a simple consequence of two facts, which actually prove something much stronger:

The first fact is that, for any smooth surface $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with positive Gauss curvature $K$, its mean curvature vector $H$ cannot vanish.  This is because the Gauss equation says that for any smooth surface in flat space, we have $K = |H|^2 - |I\!I_0|^2$, where $I\!I_0$ is the trace-free part of the second fundamental form.  In particular, if $K>0$ everywhere, then $H$ is a nowhere vanishing normal vector field on the surface.

The second fact is an old differential topology result of Whitney that says that, when $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is embedded smoothly in $\mathbb{R}^4$, its normal bundle has no nonvanishing (continuous) section.  This is not obvious; Whitney proved it using his obstruction theory for sphere bundles.  See his *On the topology of differentiable manifolds*, Lectures in Topology, University of Michigan Press, 1941.

Granted these facts, it is immediate that, for any smooth embdding of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^4$, there must be a point of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ where the induced metric has non-positive Gauss curvature. *A fortiori*, a metric of *constant* positive Gauss curvature on $\mathbb{RP}^2$ cannot be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^4$.  (This is essentially the argument that Gromov and Rohklin give in Appendix 4 of their 1970 article *Embeddings and immersions in Riemannian geometry* , though their argument for the first fact (from differential geometry) seems less immediate to me than just using the Gauss equation, as I did above.  But, eye of the beholder, etc.)

As far as I know, it is still an open problem whether $\mathbb{RP}^2$ can be smoothly *immersed* into $\mathbb{R}^4$ so that the induced metric has positive Gauss curvature (let alone *constant* positive Gauss curvature).